# C++ deleting node from middle of list

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I'm in a summer OO class and we need to write a function to delete a node from the middle of a linked list. I'm really close but there are a few problems. My code iterates through the linked list successfully but there is trouble actually deleting the node once the loop finds the node. Here's my function so far:

```
template< class NODETYPE >
bool List< NODETYPE >::removeMiddle( NODETYPE &value, int i )
{
    ListNode <NODETYPE> * tempPtr = firstPtr;
    ListNode <NODETYPE> * prevPtr ;
    int counter=1;

    if ( isEmpty() )
        return false;
    if (i <= 0)
        return false;

    while (tempPtr != 0 && counter < i){
        counter++;
        if ( firstPtr == lastPtr )
        firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
    else
        firstPtr = firstPtr->nextPtr;
            prevPtr = tempPtr;
            tempPtr = tempPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if (counter == i){
            value = tempPtr->data;  // data being removed
            delete tempPtr;
        }
    }

    return true;
    RecordCounter--;
}
```

Comment: What is the trouble, specifically? Can you describe the problem?

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to reserve shouting UPPERCASE IDENTIFIERS for macros.

Comment: The indentation is wrong, and that helps hide the fact that the curly braces are unbalanced. Consider as a coding style always using curly braces *and* always producing the right indentation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I guess that is just a guideline. I have always followed it, but in my current company (where there is a huge codebase and thousands of developers, so this is not something simple to change) template arguments are also all uppercase. Just saying.

Comment: `return true; RecordConter--`... the last statement is unreachable. Another advice would be to always compile at the highest warning level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to change the previous node so that it no longer points to the node you delete.

You want something (largely) similar to:

```
if ( counter == i-1 ) //next node is the one you want to delete
{
    aux = tempPtr->nextPtr->nextPtr;   //retain next next node
    delete tempPtr->nextPtr;           //delete next node
    tempPtr->nextPtr = aux;            //current node now points to the node after the deleted one
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you this fixed my deletion error. There's one (minor) bug left. I'm not sure if you will be able to help though. When the node is deleted output to the console is supposed to say the value of the node being deleted. For some reason it says the wrong one. For example- 

The list is: 1 2 3 4 5 
Enter position to delete: 3
1 removed from list
The list is: 1 2 4 5

Comment: @ConnorBlack might be because you return before you decrement the counter?

Comment: Good to fix but that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Whoops sorry, there was no error in the code. Eclipse console was just being funky. You get the check

Answer (score 2):

My first guess without any more specifics is that you are not maintaining the list integrity. Though I'm very rusty at C++.

You are removing the tempPtr and tracking the prevPtr... but not re-linking the two halves of the list after the delete.

```
prevPtr->nextPtr = tempPtr->nextPtr
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to adjust the links in the list. The node is still there after the `delete`, but now it's invalid. Ooops!

This function is useful:

```
NODETYPE* unlink( NODETYPE*& pNode )
{
    NODETYPE* const result = pNode;

    pNode = pNode->nextPtr;
    return result;
}
```

Call it passing in the `nextPtr` that points to the node you want to delete. You get back a pointer to the node, with the list relinked so the node is no longer in the list. Now you can `delete` that node.

What to do if you only have a pointer directly to the node that you want to delete, and the list is singly linked? Well, Donald Knuth once asked that as an exercise in his The Art of Computer Programming (if I recall correctly). One solution is to swap the data with the next node, then delete the next node.